# Is it right to say 'a bright cold day'?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adjective-position

Is it right to say [‘a bright cold day’](https://genius.com/George-orwell-nineteen-eighty-four-book-1-chapter-1-annotated) in English?

Is the order of adjectives right while saying so?

Source: *Nineteen Eighty-Four* by G. Orwell

Comment: From a writing perspective, I'd note that *bright* and *cold* actually contrast with each other -- so I'd have a *but* or at least a comma separating them: "a bright(,) (but) cold day" (pessimistic?); "a cold(,) (but) bright day" (optimistic?).

Comment: There does exist the 'Royal Order of Adjectives', but we live in democracies. And Orwell wrote his own laws (literally). I'd say he chose 'a bright cold day' to (1) avoid banality by the slightly jarring effect, (2) achieve the effect Kris mentions above while not compromising by using too staccato (... but ...) a device.

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cold+bright+day%2C+bright+cold+day&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccold%20bright%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbright%20cold%20day%3B%2Cc0) indicates a preference for 'bright cold' over 'cold bright' which surprised me.

Comment: ... @Nigel J In the recent past, since about 1950.  Coincidence?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I hadn't made the connection : _1984_ published in 1949. Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I think “a cold bright day” is preferable.

See [Ordering Multiple Adjectives](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/ordering-multiple-adjectives/), which gives the order:

1. Quantity
2. Value/opinion
3. Size
4. Temperature
5. Age
6. Shape
7. Colour
8. Origin
9. Material

“Cold” is obviously a temperature (#4), and I would categorize “bright” as a colour-like adjective here.

Comment: *Cold* is negative, *bright* is positive, too.

Comment: Was George Orwell wrong when saying so in 1984?

Comment: @user9009597 Orwell was one of those rare writers who redefines correctness in English. I'm almost certain that he would have realised that 'cold bright' was less jarring here. And chose 'bright cold' deliberately (see Kris's first comment).

Comment: @user9009597 No.  'poetic license'.

Comment: this def of bright would make it #1:  reflecting light readily or in large amounts

Comment: @lbf, no, that is not a quantity or number.

Comment: lot more photons of light on a bright day than a dull and cloudy day :)

Comment: A physical quantity is a quantity in physics that can be measured, thus a physical property that can be quantified ... Ex: of physical quantities ... light intensity

Comment: English != physics.